# Fixed image on top of scrollview in .NET MAUI / XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, layout, maui

I'm using `<ScrollView>` to make the page scrollable and I'm trying to use `<AbsoluteLayout>` to have a fixed image to the top of the page. The image must maintain its fixed position even when scrolling down the page. Placing the `<AbsoluteLayout>` outside of the `<ScrollView>` is not allowed but inside of it, it will scroll with the page. Getting rid of the `<ScrollView>` entirely would disable scrolling as well.

How do I put an fixed full width image on top of the screen, while still maintaining a scrollable page?

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto,auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" x:DataType="local:Project">
        <CarouselView Grid.Row="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding images}" 
                  IndicatorView="indicatorView"
                  IsSwipeEnabled="True">
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" 
                               SnapPointsAlignment="Center" 
                               Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding .}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        <IndicatorView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="indicatorView"/>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8,0,8,32">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <!-- Page content here -->
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <!-- What to do here??? -->
            <VerticalStackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,100,100">
                <Image Source="test.svg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

The same goes for any `<AbsoluteLayout>` element, like a floating action button, it just scrolls with the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put the ScrollView into the AbsoluteLayout. In AbsoluteLayout, you could set the image at fixed location. Consider the following code:

```
...
<AbsoluteLayout>
   <ScrollView  WidthRequest="400"  HeightRequest="500">
       <VerticalStackLayout>
       ...
       </VerticalStackLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   <VerticalStackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,100,100" >
                    <Image Source="test.svg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Then when scrolling the page, the image will stay at a fixed place.

Hope it works.

Comment: This does place the image on top. But how do you make it the width of the screen? The layouts, even the ScrollView, now use the AbsoluteLayouts width in pixels, which vary for every device.

Comment: You may try ```myscroll.WidthRequest=this.Width``` in code behind.

Comment: Glad you solve it! Happy coding!